# mutiple shortcode instance on the same page

Tags: plugin-development, google-maps, wp-localize-script

i'm building a google map shortcode plugin and i use **wp_localize_script** to pass variables to js script like (lat , lng , zoom...) . but i have an issue : when i use this shortcode twice or more in a page ,  just the first one that works .

i know that to solve my issue i should generate a script for each shortcode with unique variable names etc..

does anyone know how this can be accomplished??

Comment: edit your question to explain what does'nt work and the resultat of the debug you have done.

Comment: wp_localize_script only works once for each handle. You might want to look to create a new instance for each shortcode or mabye use html data passing through attributes like this `<div data-lat="<?php echo $latitude; ?>"></div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135821/creating-multiple-wp-localize-script-for-shortcode

Comment: @Wilco and what if we use wp_localize_script each time with different or unique handle ?

Comment: @Wilco and I  don't really understand the logic behind using data attribute for this issue .

Comment: I was able to have multiple google maps on one page, but i was using different handlers, and also the maps were in separate tabs, so only one was visible at a time, and the js code that switched between tabs also called the handlers for the different maps. So I would say if you could go with a solution that only one is visible at a given time, try something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- Shortcodes to have unique names passed to them.
- According to that name to build div with a unique id and a js
  function with a unique name.
- Load google script at the end of template(in which there is
  likelihood to have google maps).
- Run the function to display the map when it is scrolled in view.

Not gonna go into how to to pass attributes to shortcode but the code should look something like this:

```
function map_shortcode($atts){
    //deal with $atts
    ?>
    <div id="map-<?php echo $unique_name ?>"></div>
    <script>
    function mapInit<?php echo $unique_name ?>() {
                var fenway = {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>,
                lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>};

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-<?php echo $unique_name ?>'), {
                    center: fenway,
                    zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>
                });
    }
    $(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    functionWhenUserScrollsToMap(){ // I hope you can figure it out how to implement this
        mapInit<?php echo $unique_name ?>();
    }
    } );
    </script><?php
}
```

The important thing is:

- You only load once the google map script.
- Each map canvas should have unique id.
- Each map js function should have unique name.
- After the maps script has loaded you can call the functions.
- The document ready function and after the scroll should be sufficient
  for this.
- You may need to not load the google script asyncronously.